# Laptop turns off and then shows “Product information not valid” text on screen

Tags: laptop

The computer turns on for a few seconds and then the following appears on the screen… And then turns off again. What could be the problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the correct BIOS?  Did you upgrade BIOS with an incorrect version?  Have you contacted Manufacturer"s  Support line?

Comment: Did you replace the motherboard? What happens when you hit ENTER?

Comment: @John 
everything worked correctly. turned it off correctly. then I tried to turn it on and I see this. and I have no contacts. and the warranty period has ended

Comment: @Moab 
I did not do anything. I do not have time to press enter because the laptop turns off almost immediately.

Comment: Hold enter key down just before the screen shows.

Comment: @Moab i tried this. the first and second time nothing happened. the third time the laptop started up. magic!

Comment: No magic in computers - ever!.  Fails to start (load from disk), then starts (loads from disk) means hardware failure. Likely hard drive. Get the manufacturer of the drive, drive test app and test the hardware. Get memtest86.exe, make a bootable USB key and test the memory.

Comment: You will need to continue using Enter as long as the problem is not fixed. See my answer.

Comment: What is the exact make and model of this PC? I see an HP related URL in the screenshot, but what is the make and model of this HP PC?

Answer (score 2):

This message usually occurs after a motherboard replacement on an HP computer,
indicating that the BIOS is missing the System Board information.

If you have not replaced the motherboard, then the existing motherboard has experienced
a serious error and lost this information that’s "tattooed"/burnt onto it.
Contact Support for your computer, even if it's no longer under warranty.

If you wish to fix it yourself, just note that the motherboard may have a problem.
You will find below two similar articles describing the procedure used by HP
technicians for entering the required information, using data which is usually found
under the battery for a laptop:

- [Fix Missing Serial/Product Numbers for HP Laptops](http://14phoenix.blogspot.com/2013/07/fix-missing-serialproduct-numbers-for.html)
- [How to fix Product Information Not Valid error on HP G62-A19SA](http://wintegrity.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-fix-product-information-not.html)