# Need alternative to HP BIOS configuration utility

Tags: bios

I am trying to fix what I believe is an HP2000 Notebook (2015 model year) that is displaying the wonderful "Product Information not valid" message, specifically the System Board CT Number is not valid.

I went to HP's website to download the HP Bios Configuration Utility that can supposedly be used to correct the problem exactly 1.5 hours after they dropped support for it and removed it from their website.

Does anyone know of an alternative method of setting the System Board CT Number to the value that is specified on the label along with the rest of the Product Information?

The answers to all other posts with this Product Information not valid problem all tell you to download the BCU or HPDU utilities that were removed from the web 6 days ago.

If anyone that has solved this problem still has the install file for the utility that they could email to me or post on google drive then it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the Internet Archive (archive.org)?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1645952/laptop-turns-off-and-then-shows-product-information-not-valid-text-on-screen ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop turns off and then shows “Product information not valid” text on screen](https://superuser.com/questions/1645952/laptop-turns-off-and-then-shows-product-information-not-valid-text-on-screen)

Answer (score 2):

HP Bios Configuration Utility (BCU) is "a utility used to manage BIOS settings and BIOS password for supported models running a supported operating system." This allows for an administrator to change the settings in (and update the version of) BIOS from within a booted Windows environment, and supports Windows versions 7,8,8.1,10 (specifically not XP).

I did find an even more recent version than user1720292's answer, which may have been the last version ever available(?)! DOWNLOAD LINK - https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp107501-108000/sp107705.exe

The linking page for this BCU download is available on waybackmachine, so there is a good chance it'll be there for a while, but whether the FTP keeps serving it is another thing (let me know if it doesn't and i'll host it elsewhere).

As an alternative, "HP provides a WMI interface that can be used for querying and modifying BIOS settings on their hardware models. This means that we can use PowerShell to directly view and edit BIOS settings without the need for a vendor specific program." I have linked the original article here - https://www.configjon.com/hp-bios-settings-management/

References:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1880117-hp-bios-configuration-utility-bcu-hp-client-management-solutions

https://www.shouldiremoveit.com/hp-bios-configuration-utility-36544-program.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20220518041839/https://ftp.ext.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_BCU.html

Answer (score 0):

Someone in my office decided to put a BIOS password on one of the machines we use to test images. After a bunch of searching I found this in a script for Chocolaty.

https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp100501-101000/sp100599.exe

-Cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139849)